# Tools for solving a system of equations parametrically

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric

By what tools can I solve a system of equations parametrically? What I have is in a shape of below and I want to solve for $x$, $y$ and $z$.

[image]

Comment: Something seems off here.  With $x$ as given in your first equation, $x e^y + (1-x) e^z = e^a$ and $(x e^{y+z} - x + 1)^{2n} e^{-2nz} = e^{2na}$.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.